# this pointing to window in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, this

This works in chrome, FF and IE >9 as far as i know.
however it doesn't work in IE8. the console says "the object does not accept the method or property" (or something like that, it's in spanish and i dont know the exact words in english)
after some debugging, i have noted that `this` doesn't have the function i'm inside but the `window` object.

```
var slider = function(sel, pagination, paginationThumbs, form_factor)
{
    var that = this;

    (some code)

    this.init = function(sel,pagination,paginationThumbs,form_factor)
    {
        (more code)         
    }

    this.init(sel,pag,paginationThumbs,form_factor);   //it blows here

};
```

later i call it like this

```
slider('.sliderClass',3,true,0.75);
```

any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: Those are all custom properties and variables, and there's no indication of how the function is called and what the scope should be ?

Comment: Is that function supposed to be called with `new slider(…)` but was called as only `slider(…)`? Anyhow, there should be no reason that prevents you from assigning a `.init` property.

Comment: edited for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be happening is `this` is actually referring to the window object that IE is not allowing access to for some odd reason

What you could do is when calling slider call it like `new slider(/* params */);`

or instead of saying `this.init = function(){};`

you could put `var init = function(){};`

and then calling it is as simple as `init();`

```
var slider = function(sel, pagination, paginationThumbs, form_factor)
{
    var that = this;

    (some code)

    var init = function(sel,pagination,paginationThumbs,form_factor)
    {
        (more code)         
    }

    init(sel,pag,paginationThumbs,form_factor);   //it blows here

};
```

Comment: Since you marked this as the correct answer: does that mean that IE was not allowing access to the window object? I would be surprised that's the case. I would say the 'this' was indeed the window object, which simply does not have a method called 'init'.  
Were all of the changes proposed here necessary to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Use

> new slider('.sliderClass',3,true,0.75);

instead of

> slider('.sliderClass',3,true,0.75);